# How to know which cell in tableview has been selected

Tags: uitableview, swift, tableview

I have got a view controller which contains a tableview, this tableview contains dynamic cells done in storyboard. Most cells contain a textfield and in the view controller i need to detect when the textfields have been selected and which cell it was. (I load a popover pointing to the cell, and this must be called from the view controller).

Cell code

```
import UIKit

class AddNew_Date_Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    func loadItem(var data:NSArray) {
        Label.text = data[0] as? String
    }
}
```

ViewControllerCode

```
import UIKit

class AddNewDetailView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {


   @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var items : NSMutableArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch(items[indexPath.row][1] as! Int)
        {
             ...

             case 2:
             var cell:AddNew_Date_Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AN_Date_Cell") as! AddNew_Date_Cell
             cell.loadItem(items[indexPath.row] as! NSArray, view: self)
             cell.textField.delegate = self
             return cell

              ...
         }
     }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        //Need to know here which cell the textfield is attached to
        turn true
    }
}
```

Each time i select a textfield view I'm hitting a breakpoint in "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" however i have no idea which cell its in.

if i select the textfield in a cell "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" is never hit.

How do i find out which cell has been selected.

Thanks

Comment: How are you going to use this information? (Which cell selected)? Different approach whether you need to get the cell's NSIndexPath or the indexPath.row  in order to manipulate you items array

Comment: I am going to pull data out of the cell (current text value) and load a popover pointing to it

Comment: "popover pointing" do you mean load a popover that is "visually" pointing at the  cell?

Comment: Yes so it's visually pointing at the cell but I also want to pull data out the specific cell class

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the interactions from user off while the text field is not been edit, in cellForRowAtIndexPath add this line

```
cell.textField.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath you will need to enable again for edition otherwise the user won't be to touche it if they want to and call first responder:

```
cell.textField.userInteractionEnabled = true
cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

once the user finish editing in textFieldShouldEndEditing you disable the interaction again:

```
cell.textField.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

This way the cellForRowAtIndexPath will always be called but will be up to you to set the user to use the correct UITextField.

I hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom cell class with a delegate protocol letting you know when a text field has started editing.

The custom cell would be the delegate of the text field and the view controller would be the delegate of the custom cell.

For a basic example, your cell class could look like the following:

```
import UIKit

protocol TextFieldCellDelegate {
    func textFieldCellDidBeginEditing(cell: TextFieldCell)
}

class TextFieldCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var delegate: TextFieldCellDelegate?
}

extension TextFieldCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        delegate?.textFieldCellDidBeginEditing(self)
    }
}
```

And your view controller would implement the method like this:

```
extension ViewController: TextFieldCellDelegate {
    func textFieldCellDidBeginEditing(cell: TextFieldCell) {
        println(cell)
        // Do something with cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the index of your cell write the below code in func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)

```
    var index = 0
    var position: CGPoint = textField.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.<your_table_outlet_name>)
    if let indexPath = self.<your_table_outlet_name>.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position)
    {
        index = indexPath.row
    }
```